# Get a word before regex from character variable

Tags: r

I want to get a variable name which is before `in (?)` characters.
For instance:
`expect_equal("x", foo("select * from t where x in (?)"))`

this is my try:

```
stmt <- "select * from t where x in (?)"
idxParam <- gregexpr("x in\\(?", stmt)[[1]]
substring(stmt, idxParam, idxParam + 1)
```

but when the length of the word is > 1 then it fails... Maybe there is a substring function which takes as parameters first letter of the word and finishes on space  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
string <- "select * from t where x in (?)"
str_extract(string, "\\w+(?=\\s+in)")
```

This solution uses a positive lookahead to extract the first word that comes before `\\s+in`. Where `\\s+` is any number (>0) of spaces.

Can easily be translated 
into base R:

```
sub(".+(\\w+)(?=\\s+in).+", "\\1", string, perl = TRUE)
```

**EDIT:** a non-regex solution that can also deal with many `in`'s:

```
string_split <- strsplit(string, " ")[[1]]
string_split[which(string_split == "in") - 1]
```

Comment: can I use your last solution in my commercial app?

Comment: thank you (I will put link to your account in the documentation of this package)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way:

```
stmt <- "select * from t where x in (?)"
stmt_trimmed <- sub(" in \\(\\?\\)","", stmt) # [1] "select * from t where x"
tail(strsplit(stmt_trimmed," ")[[1]],1)
# [1] "x"
```

I don't know exactly what you tried to do but some mistakes were not escaping the `?` and forgetting a space after `in`

**Re: how about this: select * from t where x in (?) and y in (?)**

```
x <- "select * from t where x in (?) and y in (?)"
pattern <- " ([^ ]+) in \\(\\?\\)"
raw_matches <- regmatches(x,gregexpr(pattern,x))
clean_matches <- gsub(pattern,"\\1",raw_matches[[1]])
clean_matches
# [1] "x" "y"
```

Comment: how about this: `select * from t where x in (?) and y in (?)` ? Your result: `"(?)"`